# Android center view in FrameLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, gravity

I have a FrameLayout in which I have 2 controls: 
- a custom view which draws a image and some text on it
- a textview with a text

I want to center both in the FrameLayout but I can't manage to do it. The Texview is centered just fine, my cusom view remains on the left side, when I make it visible.

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/CompassMap"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:gravity="center">

             <view class="com.MyView"
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="CENTERED" /> 
</FrameLayout>
```

To Mathias, I don't do anything in the constructor, it's just simple

```
   public class MyMapView extends View {

private int xPos = 0; 
private int yPos = 0;
private Bitmap trackMap;

private Matrix backgroundMatrix;
private Paint backgroundPaint;

private Bitmap position;
private Matrix positionMatrix;
private Paint positionPaint;

public MyMapView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public MyMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public MyMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

backgroundMatrix = new Matrix();
backgroundPaint = new Paint();
backgroundPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);

position = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.position);
positionMatrix = new Matrix();

positionPaint = new Paint();
positionPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();

    if (trackMap!=null)
    {
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(trackMap, height, height, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, backgroundMatrix, backgroundPaint);

    }

        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.translate(xPos-position.getWidth()/2, yPos-position.getHeight()/2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(position, positionMatrix, positionPaint);

        canvas.restore();
}

    public void updatePosition(int xpos, int ypos, Bitmap trackImage)
    {
        xPos=xpos;
        yPos=ypos;
        trackMap = trackImage;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your custom view extended from? Sure you're handling the parameters in your constructor?

Comment: Is there any special reason you have to use a FrameLayout and is the TextView to be displayed on top of the View?

Comment: Yeah, the FrameLayout won't let you do that. It's really just for holding a single view. If you add more to it than that it will have the exact behavior you are mentioning, it simply adds elements in a vertical stack by pinning to the upper left. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'd suggest a RelativeLayout instead of a FrameLayout.

Assuming that you want to have the TextView always below the ImageView I'd use following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that if you set the `visibility` of an element to `gone` then the space that element would consume is gone whereas when you use `invisible` instead the space it'd consume will be preserved.

If you want to have the TextView on top of the ImageView then simply leave out the `android:layout_alignParentTop` or set it to `false` and on the TextView leave out the `android:layout_below="@id/imageview"` attribute. Like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Your explanation looks very good and it should work in my case, but it doesn't.  In my RelativeLayout I have more than I said: 2 custom views, a LinearLayout, a Button and a TextView. What is curious that everything works exept my custom view. The other custom view is not influenced as it as fill_parent attributes. But, I am trying to see if I didn't missed someething. Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of your custom view?

Comment: I added the entire code of the custom view on the question. Basically draws a big image as background and a smaller one on x,y position.

Comment: This only works as expected if you specify a src to your ImageView. If you are trying to put text (or buttons or whatever) below a ImageView that will be populated later you'll run in to some trouble because you won't be able to know the size of your buttons or whatever until well after onResume() has finished.

Comment: You want to avoid RelativeLayouts wherever possible. Each RelativeLayout requires 2 measurement passes - therefore nested RelativeLayouts have an exponential measure time. Each time you add a new nested RelativeLayout, your measurement time doubles.

Comment: Cannot be the correct answer. It's a workaround for the question.

Comment: Please see the comment on the answer below which I 100% agree with and states that: "this 'answer' changed the question instead of answering it". We see this type of responding often where the response is beside the point, and changes the intent of the OP. This type of "non-responding" should not be deemed acceptable on this site.

Answer (score 430):

We can align a view in center of the `FrameLayout` by setting the `layout_gravity` of the child view.

In XML:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

In Java code:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Note: use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` not the others existing LayoutParams

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other one changes the question rather than answering it.

Comment: Y this solution not worked for me.Adding Imageview in the center of Frame layout.cap = new ImageView(CameraActivity.this);
  LayoutParams params2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
  cap.setLayoutParams(params2);
  cameraView.addView(cap);

Comment: Now its worked for me. My mistake was i was imported wrong package. After 4 hours i got my mistake that the Actual package should import is android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

Comment: @Akanksha that is *the only* correct answer :) you guys must use  FrameLayout.LayoutParams to center a view into FrameLayout.

Answer (score 9):

### Just follow this order

You can center any number of child in a `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    >
    <child1
        ....
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        .....
        />
    <Child2
        ....
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

> #### So the key is
>
> adding `android:layout_gravity="center"`in the child views.

#### For example:

I centered a **CustomView** and a **TextView** on a `FrameLayout` like this

> Code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:lottie_fileName="red_scan.json"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Networks Available: 1\n click to see all"
        android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

> Result:

[image]

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me. I have a `FrameLayout` that contains one `TextureView` and two `SurfaceView`. With this (and the `setZOrderOnTop(true);` on the Surfaces I have finally all centered overlaying

Comment: This is the real answer here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set 'center_horizontal' and 'center_vertical'  or just 'center' of the layout_gravity  attribute of the widget

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MovieActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainerMovie"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3a3f51b5"
       />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/movieprogressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center a view in Framelayout, there are some available tricks. The simplest one I used for my Webview and Progressbar(very similar to your two object layout), I just added `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Here is complete XML in case if someone else needs the same thing to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebviewPDFActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />


</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my output

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025031/962916, this works for me to center a TabLayout inside FrameLayout.

[image]

```
final TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
// Configure TabLayout...
final FrameLayout tabLayoutContainer = new FrameLayout(this);
tabLayoutContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

final FrameLayout.LayoutParams tabLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                dpToPx(28));
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams containerLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                dpToPx(48));


tabLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
tabLayoutContainer.setLayoutParams(containerLayoutParams);
tabLayoutContainer.addView(tabLayout, tabLayoutParams);
```